# bash: don't prompt the select case statement from a script - possible?

Tags: bash, shell, select

I have a script which I usually run by hand. It prints some variables and asks me twice if those are correct:

```
echo "Is this correct?"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yn in
        Yes ) break;;
        No ) exit;;
    esac
done
```

Works perfectly.

Now however, I have been asked to automate the task completely - in other words, it shouldn't prompt me anymore and just run through.

However, I would like to retain the prompting for the normal case when I run it manually.

Is it possible to set a flag to bash or something which would just skip over the select statement? I know it's kinda silly but was wanting to see if I have an easy way out without having to completely remove that section or having to write a second script without that.

Comment: Run `yes Yes | script.sh`.

Comment: you mean echo "yes yes" | script .sh @Choroba

Comment: @transient_loop You mean `yes 1 | script.sh` -- you give a numeric answer for a select, unless you use `case $REPLY ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `test -t fd` to tell if the FD is connected to a terminal or not. When the test succeeds, prompt for input, otherwise skip it.

```
if [ -t 0 ]; then
    echo "Is this correct?"
    select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
        case $yn in
            Yes ) break;;
            No ) exit;;
        esac
    done
fi
```

Comment: Don't you need to give a file descriptor for -t: `[ -t 0 ]` for stdin -- I didn't think it had a default.

Comment: I wanted the `yes 1 | script.sh` solution first, because it would not require any change. But this is much more transparent for anyone else using the script.

Comment: is FD - in this case 0 - the fd for the current script?

Comment: 0 = stdin, 1 = stdout, 2 = stderr

Comment: Seems I have so much to learn still....So what is this testing? Basically if STDIN is not set?